# addition of two numbers using textfield

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, uitextfield, nsnumberformatter

I am new to objective c,so plz me help with this...
i have used three textfields in the interface builder
textfield1 inputs the first number
textfield2 inputs the second number

and i have created a button called sum which will calculate the sum
and textfield(ans) will display the result

.h file code

```
 {
      IBOutlet UITextfield txtfield1;
      IBOutlet UITextfield txtfield2;
      IBOutlet UITextfield ans;
 }
 -(IBAction)add;
```

.m file code

```
 -(IBAction)add
  {
      int result=[txtfield1.text intValue]+[txtfield2.text intValue];
      ans.text=[NSString StringWithFormat:@"%d",result];
  }
```

The program runs fine,but i want only integer values to be entered in the textfield,if i enter alphabets and click on the sum button i get 0 as the ans,what can i do so that user gets an error when he inputs alphabets..thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is a delegate method that let's you allow only certain characters to be in the text field.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string { 
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0);
}
```

This returns YES and therefore allows only characters that are **not** in the decimalDigitCharacterSet character set.

Comment: thanks i implemented your method but i cant use backspace why is that?

Comment: That's because it tries to replace characters in a certain range with 'nothing' and 'nothing' is not a number. Try checking if `[replacementString isEqual:@""]` and return `YES` to allow backspace.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it, is to change the Keyboard to numeric only, and you can do that right from the Interface Builder, go to the UITextField properties and near the bottom of textfield you will see the option Keyboard, change it to: Number Pad

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the UITextFieldDelegate method [textFieldShouldReturn:] in your controller.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSDecimalNumber *n = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:textField.text];
    if( [n notANumber] ) {
       // This means the user entered an invalid number;
       return NO;
    }
    return YES; // Do something with the number it is valid.
}
```

This will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSTextFieldCell` subclass (or the appropriate one for iOS; the code below is 100% valid for pure Cocoa), like that :

**Interface**

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface decimalCell : NSTextFieldCell

@end
```

**Implementation**

```
#import "decimalCell.h"
#import "NumberFormatter.h"

@implementation decimalCell

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib{

    NumberFormatter *formatter = [NumberFormatter withAllowedCharacters:@"0123456789"];
    [self setFormatter:formatter];

}

@end
```